# How to get vocabulary after Sklearn ColumnTransformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to get vocabulary after ColumnTransformer

This is my code:

```
features = df[["content", "numeric1", "numeric2"]]
results = df["label"]

features = features.to_numpy()
results = results.to_numpy()

# Creating vectorizer
transformerVectoriser = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('vector_char', TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='char', ngram_range=(2, 6), max_features = 2500, lowercase = True), 0),
                                                        ('vector_word_1', TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 1), max_features = 10000, lowercase = True), 0),
                                                        ('vector_word_2', TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(2, 2), max_features = 4500, lowercase = True), 0),
                                                        ('vector_word_3', TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(3, 3), max_features = 750, lowercase = True), 0)],
                                          remainder='passthrough'
                                          )

print(transformerVectoriser.vocabulary_)
```

Im getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'ColumnTransformer' object has no attribute 'vocabulary_'
```

I have also tried this:

```
features = transformerVectoriser.fit_transform(features)
print(features.vocabulary_)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
AttributeError: vocabulary_ not found
```

I have also tried this:

```
transformerVectoriser.fit(features)  
print("Stem vocabulary:")
print(transformerVectoriser.transformers_[0].vocabulary_)

Error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'vocabulary_'
```

And this:

```
transformed_features = transformerVectoriser.fit_transform(features) 

print("Stem vocabulary:")
print(transformed_features.transformers_[0].vocabulary_)

Error: AttributeError: transformers_ not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the four individual transformers in your `ColumnTransformer` has its own vocabulary. You can access the four transformers via `transformerVectoriser.transformers_`, ie

```
transformerVectoriser = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('vector_char', TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='char', ngram_range=(2, 6), max_features = 2500, lowercase = True), 0),
                                                        ('vector_word_1', TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 1), max_features = 10000, lowercase = True), 0),
                                                        ('vector_word_2', TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(2, 2), max_features = 4500, lowercase = True), 0),
                                                        ('vector_word_3', TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(3, 3), max_features = 750, lowercase = True), 0)],
                                          remainder='passthrough'
                                          )

transformerVectoriser.fit(features)  
# or transformed_features = transformerVectoriser.fit_transform(features) 

print("Stem vocabulary:")
print(transformerVectoriser.transformers_[0][1].vocabulary_)
print("~~")
print("Word vocabulary:")
print(transformerVectoriser.transformers_[1][1].vocabulary_)
print("~~")
print("Bigram vocabulary:")
print(transformerVectoriser.transformers_[2][1].vocabulary_)
print("~~")
print("Trigram vocabulary:")
print(transformerVectoriser.transformers_[3][1].vocabulary_)
```

Comment: When I do transformerVectoriser.fit(features) , i get error AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'vocabulary_', when I do transformed_features = transformerVectoriser.fit_transform(features)  , I get this error AttributeError: transformers_ not found

Comment: Please check updated question, I have added what I have tried

Comment: My mistake, I forgot `transformers_` is a list of tuples. As described [in the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.transformers_), the second element of the tuple is the fitted transformer.